# How to implement Teachable Machine RTD inside React Native?

Tags: react-native, tensorflow, object-detection

I am looking for a way to integrate a tensorflow.js model into my react-native application which is built using EXPO.
The model needs to **be able to access the camera** to **detect real-time** sign-language letters.

My current solution:
Train a model via [Google's Teachable Machine](https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/) platform and use their code.

 The platform supplies a Web script that I uploaded to the cloud.

 You can see the website [here](https://whatever.tiiny.site/)

 Using the 'react-native-webview' I was able to present the site inside my app.

```
<WebView source={{uri: 'https://whatever.tiiny.site/'}}  style={{ marginTop: 20 }} />
```

**However**, it feels like cheating and doesn't look very good.

 I also built my own React.js project with the sign-language model, and tried to convert it to react-native. It failed as well.

I know react-native released a tflite-react-native, tensorflowjs-react-native packages and I have read time and again their documentation but I wasn't able to convert it to my needs.

BTW:
I also found this project: 
https://github.com/expo/examples/tree/master/with-tfjs-camera 
which is very close to what I need, but they are using '@tensorflow-models/mobilenet' and I need to use my own tensorflow model.

Relevant\similar posts: 
[how to use teachable machine model in react native expo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64441725/how-to-use-teachable-machine-model-in-react-native-expo)

Comment: This video and code is an example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9sRM_VtARug&list=LL&index=1 . However, when I compare against the web version it's inaccurate and the not the same. It just doesn't work with pizza vs something else where the web version is 100% accurate.